# how to use this conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions

Would you tell me if the bold parts are correct?

A.This function **can be so precisely used in the following formula that** no other function can be used or satisfy the formula.

BThis function **can be so used in the following formula that** no other function can be used or satisfy the formula.

Comment: I don't understand how *the way that you use a function* (from ***so***) could prevent any other function from being used. Either an alternative method works or it doesn't - how can that be affected by the way in which you use the first function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The B option,

> This function can be so used in the following formula that no other function can be used or satisfy the formula.

is technically correct, but is over-complicated. The term that I like to use (because I'm a programmer, and this term pops up a lot in programming) is [obfuscated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate).

The A option may be correct, but it is too obfuscated to be used without a doubt.

A much better option would be:

> This function can be used in the following formula **so that** no other function can be used <strike>or satisfy the forumula</strike>.

Now the reason that I crossed out the end there is because it makes no sense, and I can't really tell what you were trying to say. If you meant to say that no other function can be used and that no other function can satisfy the formula, then your sentence should look like this:

> This function can be used in the following formula so that no other function can be used or can satisfy the formula.

The verb needs to be repeated a second time in this case to clarify what you're talking about.